# Issues with ui bootstrap modal CSS and printing

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am creating a webpage using angularjs and ui bootstrap to create modals. Then I have javascript to print just the modal. However, I am having an issue with my CSS. Firstly, for some reason (most likely because my CSS is messed up) the text is extending outside the div they belong in. Specifically, the ingredients and nutrition facts within the div with the class "onerow" are extending below the div with the class "modal-body".

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fxvD6MTvbEHsaonLR669?p=preview

Furthermore, I have some javascript to print just the modal pane. It seems to work except for the fact that for some reason the thick solid black borders in the nutrition facts become borders with rounded corners. Again, refer to the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fxvD6MTvbEHsaonLR669?p=preview) to better see what I am talking about.

Here is the html that makes up the modal:

```
<div class="modal-header" id="modalHeader" style="text-align: center;">
    <h3 class="modal-title">PLU# {{productData.PLU}} -- {{productData.Dept}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
    <div ng-show="!pluValid" style="text-align:center;">
        PLU {{productData.PLU}} not found in Database
    </div>
    <div class="onerow" ng-show="pluValid">
        <div class="col6">
            <div style="text-align: center;">{{productData.Desc1}} {{productData.Desc2}}</div>
            <br />
            <br />
            Ingredients:
            <br />
            {{productData.Ingredients}}
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <b>UPC NUMBER</b>
                <br />
                {{productData.UPC}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col6 last" id="nutritionfacts" ng-show="!areFacts">
            <table style="width:100%;" cellspacing:0 cellpadding:0>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;" class="header">Nutrition Facts</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">N/A</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col6 last" id="nutritionfacts" ng-show="areFacts">
            <table style="width:100%;" cellspacing:0; cellpadding:0;>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;" class="header">Nutrition Facts<br /><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Serving Size     {{productData.ServSize}}
                            <br />
                            Servings Per Container     {{productData.ServPer}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 7px">
                        <td style="background-color: #000000;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="line">Amount Per Serving</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="label">Calories
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.Calories}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding-top: 1px; float: right;" class="labellight">Calories from Fat
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.CaloriesFat}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="line">
                                <br />
                                <div class="dvlabel" style="text-align: right;">% Daily Value<sup>*</sup></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="label">Total Fat
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.TotalFat}}g</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dv">{{productData.PerFat}}%</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="indent">
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="labellight">Saturated Fat
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.SatFat}}g</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dv">{{productData.PerSatFat}}%</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="indent">
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="labellight">Trans Fat
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.TransFat}}g</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="label">Cholesterol
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.Cholesterol}}mg</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dv">{{productData.PerCholesterol}}%</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="label">Sodium
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.Sodium}}mg</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dv">{{productData.PerSodium}}%</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="label">Total Carbohydrates
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.Carbs}}g</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dv">{{productData.PerCarbs}}%</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="indent">
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="labellight">Dietary Fiber
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.Fiber}}g</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dv">{{productData.PerFiber}}%</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="indent">
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="labellight">Sugars
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.Sugars}}g</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="label">
                                    Protein
                                    <div class="weight">{{productData.Protein}}g</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 7px">
                        <td style="background-color: #000000;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="vitamins">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Vitamin A &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.VitA}}%</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">•</td>
                                        <td>Vitamin C &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.VitC}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Calcium &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Calc}}%</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">•</td>
                                        <td>Iron &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Iron}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Vitamin D &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.VitD}}%</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">•</td>
                                        <td>Vitamin E &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.VitE}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Thiamine &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Thia}}%</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">•</td>
                                        <td>Riboflavin &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Ribo}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Niacin &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Niac}}%</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">•</td>
                                        <td>Vitamin B6 &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.VitB6}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Folate &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Folate}}%</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">•</td>
                                        <td>Vitamin B12 &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.VitB12}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Biotin &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Biotin}}%</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">•</td>
                                        <td>Phosphorus &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Phos}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Zinc &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Zinc}}%</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">•</td>
                                        <td>Magnesium &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Mag}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Iodine &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Iodine}}%</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">•</td>
                                        <td>Copper &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Copper}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Pantothenic Acid &nbsp;&nbsp; {{productData.Acid}}%</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="line">
                                <div class="labellight">
                                    *Percent Daily Values are based on a 2000 calories diet. Your daily values may be higher or lower depending on your calories needs.
                                    <table border=0 width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="30%">Calories:</td>
                                            <td width="20%" style="text-align:left">2000</td>
                                            <td width="20%" style="text-align:left">2000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="line labellight" style="width: 100%;">
                                <table border=0 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="30%">Total Fat</td>
                                        <td width="30%">Less Than</td>
                                        <td width="20%" style="text-align:left">65<i>g</i></td>
                                        <td width="20%" style="text-align:left">80<i>g</i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="30%">Sat Fat</td>
                                        <td width="30%">Less Than</td>
                                        <td width="20%" style="text-align:left">20<i>g</i></td>
                                        <td width="20%" style="text-align:left">25<i>g</i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="30%">Cholesterol</td>
                                        <td width="30%">Less Than</td>
                                        <td width="20%" style="text-align:left">300<i>mg</i></td>
                                        <td width="20%" style="text-align:left">300<i>mg</i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Sodium</td>
                                        <td>Less Than</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left">2400<i>mg</i></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left">2400<i>mg</i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">Total Carbohydrates</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left">300<i>g</i></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left">375<i>g</i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Dietary Fiber</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left">25<i>g</i></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left">30<i>g</i></td>
                                    </tr>      
                                </table>
                                <div class="line">
                                    Calories per gram:
                                    <br />
                                    Fat 9 - Carbohydrate 4 - Percent 4 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="print()">Print</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `table` content requires more then the div width.

A very simple fix to start with is using the `overflow` CSS property in the #nutritionfacts div.

```
#nutritionfacts {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  overflow: scroll; 
}
```

As for the modal border-radius problem, you need to override the default `.modal-content` class which in bootstrap styles has a `border-raidius: 6px` rule.

Comment: Sorry but that's not working. The nutrient facts still extend vertically below the modal-body div that they are situated in.